# ExcelDNA C# xll - When using the formula they suddenly disappear if Ctrl+Z is accidentally pressed?

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts, excel-dna

ExcelDNA C# xll - When using the formula they suddenly disappear if Ctrl+Z is accidentally pressed?!

Has anyone experienced this? The behavior of my code (xll addin calls another custom dll) is as expected and we're (my manager and I) now testing it and she saw this behavior. I can also reproduce it too.

Is it specific to something in ExcelDNA or has anyone seen this in Excel?

We know, being seasoned developers since the 90s, about the standard Ctrl+Z behaviour, however the Ctrl+Z behaviour should just undo the edits performed in other areas of the standard sheet however it wipes out the custom function (really calling C# xll).

Also, the custom returns a 2d array / array formula. Is it something to do with array formulae?

Comment: Ctrl+z is typically the shortcut for undo. This sounds like the expected behaviour, unless you want to elaborate more on 'When using the formula they suddenly disappear'

Comment: Oh yes I know that Ctrl+Z is typical behaviour across MS (and many other) apps. What I meant is, and I'll edit the post, that we perform other edits, which MS should reverse, but it wipes out the custom function completely.

Comment: Is is possible that your add-in is internally running a macro, triggered by the function? (E.g. a call to ExcelAscynUtil.QueueAsMacro would work like this) That might change the sheet and formulas in unexpected ways.

Comment: @Govert - Hey I had forgotten bout this, as early on I was using async/callback type stuff. Maybe I forgot about it (as I'm up to my neck in MDX queries with it now!!). I will check.

Comment: Thanks. I checked and I am not using any QueueAsMacro stuff. I did just reproduce it again and this is what happens. I run my custom function (which accepts simple words and arrays to then construct elaborate MDX to fire against a remote cube and I then convert this all back to a 2D array). If I do Ctrl+Z after running the function completing with Ctrl + Shift + Enter it runs. If I perform Ctrl+Z it wipes out the array formula completely. Maybe this is standard Excel behaviour? I will check with a normal array function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, my fault! :)

Thanks for the fast comments. So this is the reason why! As you see I fire a query once loads of stuff is correctly passed in. I clean up the 2D arrays (dimensionFilters and measureFilters) removing ExcelEmpty but I'd forgotten to clean up the dimenions and measures arrays. We'd removed a value from one of the arrays for dimensions, which made the query throw an error resulting in a String going back to Excel in place of a 2D array. A subsequent Ctrl+Z removes that String meaning the formula appears to disappear.

If you do Ctrl+Y the error string/String from me re-appears and if you add back in the value that is missing the query runs and the 2D array formula reappears.

This is a complex work in progress so I will think about how to handle this situation.

Comment: If you're able to move to a version of Excel that supports the new 'dynamic array' feature, you could get rid of the Resize macro calls and have much better behaviour.

Comment: @Govert - Ah ok thanks mate. We can't yet (on client site at a major investment bank) but next year they are moving us and users to Windows 10 and Excel 2016 (as this Office/Excel is Excel 2010)

Comment: @Govert - Actually one thing I did notice yesterday after what you said re QueueAsMacro - I went back and checked my code. I wasn't using it but i noticed an old cs file I was experimenting with early on. I deleted / removed it from the VS project and rebuilt. I then ran my stuff and it was broken. I had to go into the backup from the day before and place the file back in. Does ExcelDNA keep some sort of static reference list or something?! :)